# Prisma, Apollo Client (first: x)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, prisma

I have build a backend and frontend with Prisma 1.34 and Apollo Client. However, when I try to use the "first" in my query it is giving me 400 error.

```
const DOOR_QUERY = gql`
  query DOOR_QUERY {
    doors(first: 12) {
      Id
    }
  }
`;
```

and my query

```
const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(DOOR_QUERY);
```

My backend mutation is

```
type Query {
  doors: [Door]
}
```

Am I missing something? It is working perfectly fine in the playground.

Comment: After 3 days, I have decided to ask. 10 min after I asked, I solved the problem. at my backend, I had to add first in my query

```
type Query {
  doors(where: DoorWhereInput, orderBy: DoorOrderByInput, skip: Int, after: String, before: String, first: Int, last: Int): [Door]
}
```

Comment: FWIW you can answer your own question and mark it as accepted after enough time has passed.